# CURL php query formation - how to?

Tags: php, api, post, curl

I am trying to form the following CURL post request through PHP? How do i do it, all of what i tried came back as invalid post parameters.

This is what i am trying to POST through php (i have the API_KEY, api_sig.. but dont know how put below post query through in PHP):

> curl -d
>   "api_key=KEY&sig=SIGNATURE&time_stamp=20&json=1" \
>       http://api.i.com/v1/update/

Comment: Looks like a direct shell call to curl. Take a look at a [basic curl example](http://us.php.net/manual/en/curl.examples-basic.php) using PHP's curl library. You'd send data pairs as [`CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS`](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php).

Comment: $ch = curl_init("http://api.iq.com/v1/update/");
$fp = fopen("response.txt", "d");

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FILE, $fp);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);

Like above? I am not sure how to do it in PHP - hence my question :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should work

```
$url = "http://api.iq.com/v1/update/";
$data = "api_key=API_KEY&api_sig=SIGNATURE&time_stamp=20090612111832&json=1";

$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST ,1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1); /* obey redirects */
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);  /* No HTTP headers */
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);  /* return the data */

$result = curl_exec($ch);

curl_close($ch);
```

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to following PHP code

```
 define('POSTURL', 'http://api.iq.com/v1/update/');
 define('POSTVARS', 'api_key=API_KEY&api_sig=SIGNATURE&time_stamp=20090612111832&json=1');  //removed typo
 $ch = curl_init(POSTURL);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST  ,1);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS ,POSTVARS);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER  ,1);  // RETURN THE CONTENTS OF THE CALL`
 $Rec_Data = curl_exec($ch);`
 curl_close($ch);
```

Answer (score 0):

Put everything in one line:

```
curl -d "api_key=API_KEY&api_sig=SIGNATURE&time_stamp=20090612111832&json=1" http://api.iq.com/v1/update/
```

Use `exec()` to run it, for example

```
exec("curl -d \"api_key=API_KEY&api_sig=SIGNATURE&time_stamp=20090612111832&json=1\" http://api.iq.com/v1/update/", $results);
```

`$results` holds the returned data.